# Ricoh Aficio SP 1200s driver for ubuntu

Tags: drivers, printing, ricoh

I receive blank pages when i give a print command for this multifunction printer.

When i confirmed with the engineer, they said they don't have driver for Ubuntu/Linux operation system.

although machine is working properly on windows base operating system with the help from the CD which i receive from Ricoh .

Comment: The engineer is right.  They do not provide Linux drivers.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to print to a RFG SP1210N using the Generic PCL 5 driver.

Answer (score 0):

[printer-driver-sag-gdi](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=saucy&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=printer-driver-sag-gdi) is the printer driver for **Ricoh Aficio SP** Printers.

This is provided by the Official Ubuntu Repository.

You can install it by :

```
sudo apt-get install printer-driver-sag-gdi dvi2ps-fontdata-rsp ghostscript
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. still after installing this command, i am NOT able to print files from my Ubuntu.

Comment: also, after giving command, the printer is continuously printing multiple blank pages.